# How do I update my Joomla website PHP from 7.4 to 8.1

Tags: php, database, joomla, cpanel, ionos

I bought a website template called ELOS from Themeforest many years ago. There is no support or communication assistance that is helpful. Can someone help me upgrade my Joomla website from PHP 7.4 to 8.1

The error is with my website not being compatible with PHP 8.1. When I change the PHP from 7.4 to 8.1 on my Cpanel I get an error on my my website.

I have attached a picture. This is what comes up when I change the PHP to 8.1 on my cpanel. It goes back to normal on 7.4.

I understand how Joomla works, a touch of Html and understand how servers/domains etc work. If you have a lot of patience and enjoy solving problems then please please give ema shout. Help would be much appreciated.

I can forward on any files etc. my website is [www.connormaguire.com](http://www.connormaguire.com)

[image: error after changing to php 8.1]]
[image]

This is the error shown in debug mode
[image: error in debug mode]

I have tried looking at different files/Htaccess/Php files etc. I am not a developer

Comment: You probably need to check if there's a version of Joomla which supports PHP 8.1 and upgrade to that. Messing with the joomla source code - especially when, as you admit yourself, you're not a developer - is really not a good idea.

Comment: P.S. This site is for programmers to help each other (see the [tour] and [ask]). If you're not a programmer, then realistically it's not the right place to come, because you're very likely to get technical questions, asked to provide source code, evidence of debugging, your own efforts to fix it etc. It's an encyclopaedia for programmers to find useful materials and help each other out with mutual assistance, not a free helpdesk for non-programmers. If you need a programmer and you're not a programmer, then please hire one. You're unlikely to find people here who will undercut their day jobs.

Comment: You are far more likely to receive feedback from people actually use Joomla if you ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.